# Is there always an epimorphism from a free $A$-module to a given one?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $A$ be a commutative ring. Given an $A$-module $P$, can I always construct a free module $M$ and a surjective homomorphism $f:M\rightarrow P$?

I was thinking something along the lines of tensor product construction, but can't seem to get a homomorphism working properly.

Thank you.

Comment: Take a system of generators of $P$.

Comment: ...and construct the free $\;A$-module on that set of generators (continuing the above comment's hint)

Comment: Thank you. Tried this with all the elements of $P$ for generators. Didn't seem to work for constructing $f$, but I'll try again.

Comment: Use the universal property for free modules. It gives you at once the homomorphism (even if you don't want!) :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, and canonically so: let $M$ be the free module on the elements of $P$. More generally, see [monads](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_(category_theory)).